# npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

[image]

Any idea what to do? I don't have any, other than trying what it says there, "npm install" (which produces exactly the same error...) and googling, and there doesn't seem to be an answer here in stackoverflow.

Your help is appreciated, since I'm a beginner with npm, and overly frustrated month after month...

This is the "complete log" it's referred to in the error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.9
3 info using node@v14.15.2
4 verbose npm-session 0f25ee095e558051
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall react-player@0.1.0
7 info lifecycle react-player@0.1.0~preinstall: react-player@0.1.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 4777ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 50ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
16 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4937ms
17 silly saveTree react-player@0.1.0
18 verbose stack Error: Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty.
18 verbose stack Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
18 verbose stack If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".
18 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:60:29
18 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotValue (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotAccum (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
18 verbose stack     at Object.tryCatcher (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:611:10)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:142:12)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
18 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
18 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
18 verbose stack     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
19 verbose cwd C:\Users\Daniel\Programming\Creative React-Redux\Chapter 3\react-player
20 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
21 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
22 verbose node v14.15.2
23 verbose npm  v6.14.9
24 error Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty.
24 error Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
24 error If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

### Solution:

These steps generally work for most people:

**Step 1.** Delete -lock.json file.

**Step 2.** Run,  `npm install`

**Step 3.** Run,  `npm install @babel/core --save`

Comment: yes but this happens everytime, it works for the first run, then we have to delete everytime the lock file. not a solution this one

Answer (score 14):

I fixed it like this:

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. Run "npm install" in the console

Comment: Thanks bro! I used this twice and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I tried this.

1. Delete Node modules.
2. Delete **package-lock.json** file.
3. Then on terminal run command **npm install** or **yarn** as per your package manager.

Answer (score 3):

**You can fix this problem in two simple steps.**

1. Delete **node modules** & **package-lock.json** completely.
2. Run the command **npm install** from the terminal.

*I believe, now you can install new external package.*

Answer (score 2):

Try running this

```
npm install @babel/core
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

Comment: I get exactly the same error doing this.
C:\Users\Daniel\Programming\Creative React-Redux\Chapter 3\react-player>npm i --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".     
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-08T04_03_07_758Z-debug.log

Comment: Try using npm cache clean

Comment: Also, npm install @babel/core --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: Same thing, this is so weird. I can use yarn though, yarn works.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem:

I ran into the same error when trying to install **`@material-ui/icons`** and **`@material-ui/styles`**, after installing the **`@material-ui/core`**.

> npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty.
> npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
> npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! C:\Users\Matryoshka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-07T08_05_07_220Z-debug.log
> PS E:\Projects\PortfolioSite\React-Portfolio-Website\react-portfolio-website>
> npm install @material-ui/icons
> npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty.
> npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
> npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Matryoshka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-07T08_06_04_026Z-debug.log

### Solution:

1. Delete the **package-lock.json** file.
2. Delete all the **node modules**.
3. Run the command `npm install` from the terminal.

Then, I was able to install the libraries successfully.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. yarn add @babel/core